# Strange looking rubber plant leaf

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

This one week-old leaf looks really odd. It came out with two cracks near the top of mid vein and the tip is separated from the rest of the leaf. It's gotten a deep curve on the top that seems too delicate (it looks like it'll break if i mess with it.) I wanted to know if this leaf will continue to remain the same and how I can make sure the new leaves don't come out this way? The plant stays in bright indirect sunlight and is watered when soil is dry, which is about once in 3-4days. [image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the leaf was damaged while it has been growing (curled in a “package” bud). Next time just check any damage from wind/pets/kids/bugs while the leaf is young :)